Matlab qz algorithm not reliable
I programmed my own version of the qz algorithm and, while testing it's results using the matlab qz algorithm, I found a particular case where my solution reaches an upper-triangular matrix and matlab only quasi-upper-triangular. I don't think it's an error on my behalf, because the 2x2 block matlab doesn't upper-triangularize has two real eigenvalues. Therefore my question is:'Is the matlab qz algorithm reliable or not?'
Here is the pencil in question:
A = [297 1134 -906; 11 44 -32; -67 -255 205];
B = [-147 -198 719; -3 3 20; 33 45 -161];

I can, of course, provide my program, if anyone wants to check for errors

The 5 significant figures fooled me. Both mine and the matlab qz algorithm reached the same conclusion, differing only by a huge constant. Therefore I revoke my criticism of the matlab qz function.
